# Is having two attributes in one database column ok?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I have some products that the owner can share to other users. It can be either permanent or one-time. I am designing my database on dynamoDB and I want to get some comment on this structure.

```
{
  "product1":
    {
      "sharedTo":["P+4100000000","O+411234567"]
    }
}
```

I combined sharing mode and shared account(phone number), which P represent permanent and O represent one-time. I do not need to update it. Users are only allowed to delete it or add new one.

What do you think? Any issue will cause?

Answer (score 0):

It's a personal choice. But my choice would be to use something which is easier to modify. For that reason I typically suggest using a Map type when storing nested items:

Refer to this SO post:

[Array or Map is better in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412043/array-or-map-is-better-in-database/74413051#74413051)